# Hiding the next/back button in the first/last div

Tags: jquery

How to hide the back button in the first div and put it back on the second div, similarly for the next button

The code below is working, but it does not put back the next/back button if it is not the last and the first div

```
<div class="case active">
  <div>content 1</div>
</div>

<div class="case">
  <div>content 2</div>
</div> 

<div class="case">
  <div>content 3</div>
</div> 


<div class="prev-btn">
  <span id="prev" class="btn btn-default"">Back</span>
</div>
<div class="next-btn">
  <span id="next" class="btn btn-default"">Next</span>  
</div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#next').click(function(){
                if ($('.active').next('.case').length) {
                    $('.active').removeClass('active')
                                .next('.case')
                                .addClass('active', '.case');
                    if ($('.active').next('.case').length==0) {
                        $('#next').hide()
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#prev').click(function(){
                if ($('.active').prev('.case').length) {
                        $('.active').removeClass('active')
                                .prev('.case')
                                .addClass('active');
                    if ($('.active').next('.case').length==1) {
                        $('#prev').hide()
                    }              
                } 
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: jQuery is used for DOM manipulation and you're asking a strictly DOM related question without showing the HTML. Why. Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try this, I hope it helps

```
if ($('.case:first').hasClass('active')) {
$('.prev-btn').css('display','none');
}

if ($('.case:last').hasClass('active')) {
$('.next-btn').css('display','none');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by adding

```
$('#next').click(function(){
        if ($('.active').next('.case').length) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active')
                        .next('.case')
                        .addClass('active', '.case');
            if ($('.active').next('.case').length==0) {
                $('#next').hide()
            } 

            if ($('.active').prev('.case').length!=0) {
                $('#prev').show()
            } 


        }
   } 

$('#prev').click(function(){
        if ($('.active').prev('.case').length) {
            $('.active').removeClass('active')
                        .prev('.case')
                        .addClass('active');

            if ($('.active').next('.case').length!=0) {
                $('#next').show()
            } 

            if ($('.active').prev('.case').length==0) {
                $('#prev').hide()
            } 



        }
```